# How do I make this electronics system of circuits and batteries work?

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, system

I have this:

[image: circuit]

where Battery #2 will connect with pins (like wireless earbuds) to Battery #1 so Battery #2 can get charged (from Battery #1). So Battery #2 can be easily disconnected and connected to Battery #1 just like wireless earbuds with their case.

My question is, how do I make it so that when Battery #2 is disconnected from Battery #1, Battery #2 and Circuit #2 are connected. But when Battery #2 is connected to Battery #1, the connection between Battery #2 and Circuit #2 is determined by the switch (or the state of the connection) between Battery #1 and Circuit #1? In that way, when Circuit #1 is on and Battery #2 is connected to Battery #1, Circuit #2 is also on. When Circuit #1 is off and Battery #2 is connected to Battery #1, Circuit #2 is also off. And when Battery #2 is not connected to Battery #1, Circuit #2 is on. What's the easiest way to do this with least components?

Comment: Is there any way you could word that in a way that people could understand?  It's too complicated.

Comment: @SimonB I've tried my best sorry

Comment: Description is confusing but makes sense. | B1-B2 can be joined to charge B1 from B2 (very naughty). In this mode S2 controls L1 & L2 powered from B2. | When separated S1 controls L1 from B1 and L2 is on from B2.

Comment: @JingleBells I've added a diagram of an EXAMPLE circuit. Note that if you want a two wire interface then YOU have to decide how you are going to both charge over two wires and signal the state of the switch to load 1. It's doable but needs a plan on how ypu wish to do it. See my answer.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. You want to have two parts: part #1, which contains circuit #1 and battery #1, and part #2, which contains circuit #2 and battery #2. When the two parts are disconnected from each other, both circuits should be on (that is, connected to the batteries). However, when the two parts are connected to each other, both circuits should be controlled by a single switch. Am I understanding that right? At first glance, that requirement sounds quite arbitrary; can you provide a little bit of explanation as to why you want to do this?

Comment: @TannerSwett Thank you so much for the interest, Tanner, but I think I got it figured out. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @TannerSwett  If I understand it from our discussion: When they are joined a switch controls both. When they are separated the switch controls the master and the remote is on. Along the way he noted that the remote is a ring. See link to chat above for more details.

Comment: ^ that would be correct

Comment: For what it's worth, the reason that I asked the question is to suggest a way that your post might be improved in order to make it more useful to future users of this site.

Comment: @TannerSwett Well, I'm open to edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where Battery #2 will connect with pins (like wireless earbuds) to Battery #1 so Battery #2 can get charged (from Battery #1).

**WARNING**:
It is **VERY** unwise and also **dangerous** to directly connect two batteries together in order to try to charge battery 1 from battery 2. If battery 1 is relatively discharged and battery 2 is relatively charged **VERY** high currents can flow between the two batteries.
Depending on the LiIon batteries used this could cause fire and/or  damage to the batteries.

You could add a resistor in the circuit between batteries - but this will waste energy and  needs to be sized for the worst case relative charge situation.
An  acceptable solution is to add the circuitry from a battery bank that will accept 3 to 4.2 V in and provide battery charging out. Because of the way battery banks usually work not all will operate with 3V to 4.2V in.

What will work - and it adds complexity and inefficiency is to use TWO battery bank circuits. Battery 2 inputs to the battery terminals on PB2 and outputs 5VDC. PB2 5VDC out connects to 5vDC IN on PB1 and charges battery one connected to PB1 battery terminals.

**__________________**

> My question is, how do I make it so that when Battery #2 is disconnected from Battery #1, Battery #2 and Circuit #2 are connected.   ....

You can almost do this with manual switching, and do it exactly with a relay or simple circuitry.

In both cases a 4 pin connector is used  between B1, L1 & B2, L2.
2 wires connect the batteries via a charging arrangement - see above.
2 wires are used to connect load 1 to load 2.

**Manual:**

If you don't mind having to manually switch B2-L2 when the modules are disconnected then this is an easy and low cost solution.

Provide a switch S1 between B1 - L1 and another between B2-L2.
When the connection is made charging occurs from B2 to B1 and L1 is connected to L2.
If S2 is operated both L1 & L2 are powered by B2
(If S1 is operated then both loads are powered by B1 but that is not on your requirement list).
When the connector is disconnected then B1-L1 is controlled by S1 and B2-L2 is controlled by S2.

**Automatic.**

To fully meet your description, add 2 contacts to the connector.
A relay in both modules can be operated via the 2 extra connections when the modules are connected.  The relays can connect or disconnect Bx to Lx as required when the modules are separated.

A simple electronic circuit (one or two transistors and a few resistors on each module) could replace the relays.

I could draw the related circuit, but I suggest that you look at the above descriptions and draw a circuit that matches. Ask if too hard after giving it a try.

A circuit with a 2 pin connector may be possible but with extra circuit complexity.

**_________________________**

Below is an example only circuit that meets what I understand your requirement to be.  S2 operates both loads when the two modules are joined and load2 only when separated. Load 1 is automatically powered on separation.

When plugged together:

- B2 charges B1 via a suitable charging circuit.
- Switch 2 operates Load 2 and Load 1 from Battery 2.
- Q3 is turned on via R3 and turns Q1 off.

When unplugged:

- Switch 2 operates load 2 from battery two
- Q1 is turned on by R7 so Load 1 is powered by Battery 1 .

Three wires is possible with a little more complexity.
Two wires would need "signalling" over the charging circuit and is possible but non-trivial. Use of eg optocoupled signalling as well as the two power leads would allow two wires plus the opto link.

In this mode S2 controls L1 & L2 powered from B2. | When separated S1 controls L1 from B1 and L2 is on from B2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkgrKR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the above diagram charge direction is left to right.
Assume source battery is of higher mAh than target battery.

R7 ~~= V/Ib
Ib ~= Ichg/Beta_Q1*2
Say Beta = 100 (higher available).
Say Ichg = 150 mA max.
V_R7 ~= 2.5V
R7 ~= 2.5/(0.150/100 x 2) ~~= 1K
Change Q1 to a suitably low Rdson MOSFET for much lower standby current.

R3 maybe 33k
R6 maybe 220k

MOSFETS allow much higher resistor values ane lower losses via resistor strings.

If using bipolars then eg BC327-40 / BC807-40 have higher beta so allow larger resistors.

**__________________**

This addresses the various discussions. I have not gone over it in utter detail compared to spec as the spec is somewhat fluid - and a boost converter is still needed for battery-battery charging BUT it shows how one side can auto turn on when disconnected and how both sides are controlled by one switch when connected.

Click image for larger version

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109322/discussion-on-answer-by-russell-mcmahon-how-do-i-make-this-electronics-system-of).

Comment: You constantly decline to answer my questions. || You CANNOT make it transfer charge from one battery to another when the source is less than about 0.2V above the target using TP4056s alone. You COULD use a powerbank module to step up the source to 5V and a TP4056 to use the 5V to charge the target.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sir, could you please point to which questions I haven't answered, so I can answer?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I understand that there will be a voltage drop which limits the voltage which B2 can reach while being charged. I'm not able to order a powerbank module and I need to fit the whole circuit into a ring (not exactly, but a very small space). Is there some type of a small space-efficient circuit that I can do that will do the job of supplying 5V to the second TP4056 module? If not, I could perhaps remove the second TP4056 module and put some other circuit that'll do the job?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I'm sorry if I have unintentionally missed a question or two. No disrespect. I'm just trying to make this work.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Nevermind the above. What resistor values should I use for the circuit when B1 is ~1000mAh and B2 is ~140mAh? Transistors are normal PNP transistors, but what about the resistors? Thanks :-)

Comment: [Google image search - Boost Converter schematic](https://www.google.com/search?q=boost+converter+schematic&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALeKk03g6rJlgNK-Detj7HpI6YtnQhHZSw:1592184063235&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT8YXs04LqAhWRzjgGHUUFCJsQ_AUoAXoECCoQAw&biw=2048&bih=1057)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you so much for the update! I didn't see it :P I think that would be all. I really appreciate your help. Oh, and good luck with photography :D

Comment: @JingleBells - Note that as above you are going to need a boost converter of some sort to raise the source battery above target battery voltage IF you want source to discharge without voltage limitations. IF mAh_source  is >> mAh_target and if you start with source rrasonably well charged you'll get "some charging".

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Got it, thanks. Figured, I can just put the boost converter on the "parent" side where I have much more space instead of in the "child" ring-like small side.

Comment: @JingleBells Yes indeed - I'm glad that's now clear. You can also place the TP4056 charger on the parent side and extend only the battery leads.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Hi, I made the circuit (https://i.ibb.co/GFBwSPZ/circuit.png) with the corresponding resistors and transistors on a breadboard but for some reason, Load 1 has 0.3V across it when the 4 pin connections are connected and the switch is off. The second TP4056 board (child) has 4.5V of the input voltage. (I'll buy a booster tomorrow but I don't think that's the issue). This 0.3V (when it should be 0V) results in the second battery not being able to charge (because I suppose the 0.3V circuit is drawing more current than is supplied to the battery) Do you know what might be going on?

Comment: R3 needs to go to Right-side_Out-  via  via Left-side connection. You have it going to Right-side_Input - which may not be the same.  || You have added more circuitry (extra TP4056) which is not at all bad BUT you need to be careful of changing functionality in the process. || Look carefully at my circuit and understand how it (hopefully :-) ) works so you can then decide if yours emulates it properly.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks, I believe I have some sort of an intuition about how the circuit works but I'm struggling to understand how R3 should be connected to the right side Out- via a left side connection. I really thought about it but I can't get my head around how to make the proper connections. I have this - https://i.ibb.co/qrywMLc/Capture.png but I'm pretty sure it's wrong (and it uses 5 connections).

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/R0dtgky/circuit.png I thought this would work but then I forgot that I need the parent battery to charge the child battery (not the USB to charge the child battery and parent battery...)

Comment: I have no idea how to make the proper connections :\

Comment: @JingleBells If you read back through the comments above and the thread converted to chat will find throughout that I have said that IF you want decent battery to battery charging you will need a boost converter - and that part of the circuitry from a power bank can do this - or use examples that I posted links to. | IF the base battery mAh is >> portable mAh then you can input from charged battery to 4056 and get a partial charge. It's all covered previously.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sure, but the issue isn't that enough voltage isn't supplied, the issue now is that the child circuit has 0.3V across it, which results in current being drawn from the battery while it's being charged, so it stays at a constant level and the battery doesn't charge. You get the idea.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon https://i.ibb.co/GFBwSPZ/circuit.png This is the circuit that I need to fix and the issue is that when the child and parent are connected, and when the switch is off, there's 0.3V across Load 2 when it should be 0V. That 0.3V means that the child circuit draws current and it prevents the child battery from being charged. There is 4.5V input into the child battery which I think is enough. I have ordered the boost modules and they are arriving tomorrow, but I'm not sure that the issue is not with the circuit itself.

Comment: @JingleBells You seem not to have actioned my above "R3 needs to go to Right-side_Out- via via Left-side connection. You have it going to Right-side_Input - which may not be the same. "

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I don't know how to do it. I really tried but this is what I came up with https://i.ibb.co/qrywMLc/Capture.png and it doesn't look right (it has 5 pins, even though that's not a big issue if it works). Could you please show me how to hook it up?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I just figured that the voltage is -0.27V across the child circuit, sorry for not mentioning that earlier. I tried https://i.ibb.co/GFBwSPZ/circuit.png and https://i.ibb.co/qrywMLc/Capture.png but in both cases, the voltage across the child circuit (when the switch is off and all pins connected) is -0.27V

Comment: The boost converters will arrive tomorrow so I can test with them properly (as you advised)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Do you happen to know why there's -0.27V across the child circuit when parent and child are connected and switch is off?

Comment: @JingleBells Probably because your circuit is not my circuit. You have in the latest diagram moved the pulldown to master battery negative but left the child load on master USB in negative. With the USB charger operating I'd expect what you see and with the USB charger not working the result is not easily knowable. Im plementing my cct may help. Or not :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Could you please clarify what you mean. Maybe you could draw a diagram or something because I'm really struggling to figure it out. It's the last thing I have to fix and I can leave this thread alone. I have tried doing this - https://i.ibb.co/qrywMLc/Capture.png but it produces the same -0.27V across the child circuit.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Hello?

Comment: @JingleBells Same answer as above. You have not properly copied my circuit. If you follow through my descriptions you should be able to see the difference. Your load1 bottom must return to load2 bottom, R2 bottom etc and not to USB-right pin 1. By all means keep asking if it doesn't work BUT if as I suggested you seek to understand the circuit and not just copy it (wrongly)(it happens :-))  you will be able to alter it yourself.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks for answering. I understand what you're saying and I've looked through the circuit and I understand how it works. My issue comes with connecting things. I don't know how to connect the circuit so that all requirements are satisfied and to resemble your original circuit. It seems kinda impossible.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Oh! Thanks for the diagram, I'm seeing now. But it looks to me that the child will only charge if the parent is being charged (with a USB) but that's not how I need the circuit. I need the child battery to charge from the parent battery even if the parent battery is not being charged (with the USB). I've specified that in the description.

Comment: @JingleBells Read all that I've said on the subject of parent to child charging. | In my latest  answer update nore " ...  and a boost converter is still needed for battery-battery charging  ..." and read the BIG BLACK wreiting on the diagram. | A while ago you said " ...  Figured, I can just put the boost converter on the "parent" side where I have much more space instead of in the "child" ..." and you said " ... I'll buy a booster tomorrow ..." BUT now you have served up a diagram with 2 x TP4056 so I can with what you brung.  ...

Comment: ... Once you add a boost converter you can more the source back to parent battery. I have covered all this above (several times in most cases), , you just need to work through it and understand it.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Mkay, thanks

Comment: @JingleBells Ask again if its still unclear **BUT** 1st work through everything I've said and understand it. You can filly charge the child battery from the parent ONLY if you have a boost converter. tThje BC can be in the parent. You can even have a BC + TP4056 in the parent connecting to the battery in the child. So almost zero power control components in the child (just a switch)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you for not giving up on me :-) I've looked at your original circuit and I've tried to make a circuit that has the required boost converters and I've also tried putting the child TP4056 on the parent side. Here's the circuit that I've managed to make: https://i.ibb.co/w6vzH7p/Capture.png (P.S the child boost converter is there to give the RF transmitting chip 5V so it works better) I haven't tried the circuit yet. Is everything connected properly? Should it work?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sorry, just to confirm, do you see anything wrong with this circuit: https://i.ibb.co/w6vzH7p/Capture.png?

Comment: @JingleBells Later ... - Now getting too complex on the chlld - you can move much of the child circuitry to the parent AND I think you may have changed some of the functionality. | The child can have solely battery load and switch  with all else on parent. Parent contains  USB charger for parent battery,  boost converter from parent battery to charger (on parent) for child.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Don't bother checking the circuit... it doesn't work. It still produces the weird -0.3V issue. I guess I'll have to release the product with the issue :P

Comment: @JingleBells Your cct has, as noted above, migrated away from the original spec and got more complex. The switch was originally on the child side but now is on the parent side . (I assume the child is the ring, yes?). || The Child now has the biist converter onboard - unneeded. The child only needs a switch battery and load on board plus a connector. You need to look at the fundamental spec, be sure it still does what you want and then look at each addition and location to see if it meets your spec. | There is ONE boost boost converter (on parent powering TP4056 to charge child BUT this TP4056

Comment: ... is located  on the P board. There is a 2nd 4056 to charge P battery from USB. The shutown when connected cct is on the P board. || Again: C board has switch battery load connector. Nothing else. P has 2 x 4056 and 1 x boost conv. BC powered by P bat and powers 4056 which charges C bat via connector. Other 4056 charges P bat from USB. || If your diagrams do not follow this then you are not meeting your own spec.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks for the help. I've put a booster on the child side because the child's circuit requires solid 5V to work well. I have tried and failed to put the child's TP4056 board on the parent side (because the connections don't work out). I don't mind if it's bulky or if there are a lot of things on the child side (ring side). The first step is to get the whole system working properly, but that proves to be incredibly difficult and has already consumed a lot of time and energy.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon https://i.ibb.co/m6nwZHb/final.png This is the only circuit that I've managed to make that somewhat works but has the issue of -0.3V across the child circuit when child and parent are connected and switch is off. I have a suspicion that it's not -0.3V always but is parent battery voltage - child battery voltage. Not sure though. Nevertheless, I suspect the issue comes from the fact that the parent side and child side have different grounds when connected.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I have looked at your circuit - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofEYJ.png but I was turned off by the fact that there's a wire going out from the parent's TP4056 input into the child's TP4056 input. This suggests that the child's battery can only charge if the parent battery is being charged, and I need the child's battery to charge from the parent battery even if the parent battery is not being charged (i.e. USB not connected).

Comment: re " ... but I was turned off by ..." -> that was a product of you at that stage saying that you were not at that stage going to use a BG. I ALWAYS said it was needed from proper bat-bat charging. On the diagram in LARGE black letters is says "Or boosted Out+..." and "Or boosted Out- ..." -> that was for when you finally decided to add a BC as I had always said you needed to. When you did that you moved the leads tp boosted Out+ and Our- as the text said. | Then follow the list above whoch lays out what's needed. The ring 4056 CAN be on the parent as long as your connector works properly.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I JUST GOT IT TO WORK! YAY! https://i.ibb.co/FDG3gCy/cct.png <-- This is the circuit and it works PERFECTLY! No errors, everything is how I needed it. The -0.27V issue is gone! Thank you so much, Russell! I really appreciate your help. I can't believe it finally works after a week of suffering. The power of never giving up I guess

Comment: @JingleBells I'm glad that works for you. You seem to have changed the spec and it seems more complex than needed BUT if it suits your need that's good. || Is switch on ring/child or parent? And was that always so?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Which switch? The mechanical or the circuit you gave me?

Comment: @JingleBells as in "the connection between Battery #2 and Circuit #2 is determined by the switch "

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what switch you're referring to.

Comment: @JingleBells IN YOUR QUESTION YOU SAY : -> "the connection between Battery #2 and Circuit #2 is determined by the switch " <- Is the switch that YOU refer to in that quote part of the parent or  part of the ring/child?

Comment: THE SWITCH IS IN THE PARENT and that was always so. You can clearly see it in every schematic as well as this one https://i.ibb.co/FDG3gCy/cct.png